# When I set the TAB badge, the picture of the UITabbar will disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

When I set the tabbar badge, the picture of the tabbar will disappear!
And when I long press tabbaritem item will keep flashing, and cannot be restored.

For the first time I use tabbar in the system, hope to get help

```
NSArray * myviewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:homeNav,ceshinav,msgNav,accNav, nil];
_rootContro = [[RootTabbarVC alloc]init];
[_rootContro setViewControllers:myviewControllers];
_rootContro.selectedIndex = 0;
self.window.rootViewController = _rootContro;
[self setUpTabbar];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

UITabBarItem * it = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"..." image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_cat_normal"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] selectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_cat_selected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [it setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 20, 20, 20)];
    [it setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -5)];

........The middle omit...........

NSArray *conversations = [[[EaseMob sharedInstance] chatManager] conversations];
NSInteger unreadCount = 0;
for (EMConversation *conversation in conversations) {
    unreadCount += conversation.unreadMessagesCount;
}
UIViewController *vc = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
if (unreadCount > 0) {
    vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",unreadCount];
}else{
    vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
}
```

Comment: its strange. can you show me your storyboard?

Comment: I didn't use the story board, directly written in code，I want to send screenshots, but I have not reached the level of the picture

Comment: Ok, I already expected that. You are going the really hard way. Tabbar is kind of special stuff, that contains a lot on linked ViewController, hat has this tabbedImage.image. Not sure how to handle that only with code.

Comment: I know the reason, because I give pictures too much and then set ImageInsets